# VyOS - routing in 2 networks

Tags: vyos

I do not know how to do routing between Lan#1 192.168.1.0 and Lan#2 192.168.10.0. I tried with static routing `set protocols static route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 192.168.10.0 distance '1'` but I do not understand it.

**1. Interfaces**

```
run show interfaces ethernet 
Codes: S - State, L - Link, u - Up, D - Down, A - Admin Down
Interface        IP Address                        S/L  Description
---------        ----------                        ---  -----------
eth0             192.168.1.222/24                  u/u  OUTSIDE 
eth1             192.168.10.1/24                   u/u  INSIDE
```

**2. Gateway**

```
gateway-address 192.168.1.1
```

**3. NAT**

I can do next NAT, then there is routing and internet but this (2 x NAT in network) is incorrect

```
edit nat source r 1
set outbound-interfeace eth0
set source address 192.168.10.0/24
set translation address masquerade
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's kind of late response to the question but I guess it's important for future readers. Routing between two networks/LANs/Subnets is automatic as long as both are directly connected to the VyOS router. You can check this by running the command *show ip route*. One critical thing to make sure is that in both sides of the router the devices need to point to it, that is, the devices must be configured with the gateway IP address as the addresses of the router interfaces respectively. In your example, the eth0 IP address (192.168.1.222) must be your gateway for the 192.168.1.0/24 network, and the eth1 IP address (192.168.10.1) must be your gateway for the 192.168.10.0/24 network. With that you shouldn't have any more problems.